# What this Feature Called? Can i Download a Demo

Tags: jquery, html

What is this feature in the attached image is called? Can i download a demo of it? 
[image: Jquery Based Slider]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a carousel if I am correct. It slides images around? This can be tricky at first but arent too difficult. Just google jquery carousel. Here's a link: http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55

Comment: But it have an additional feature, in which the centered images is zoomed... Also, i have an interview today and this might be included as a task, will internet be available in this kind of jquery based test?

Comment: Well good luck on your interview! You could find some JS to zoom the center image. If the html was on a server you would need internet

Answer (score 0):

Its a carousel. You can find several jquery ones out there.

Here's [a Simple Infinite Carousel with jQuery](http://www.queness.com/post/923/create-a-simple-infinite-carousel-with-jquery)
I copied the code to jsfiddle for you to check out
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/h9X6Y/)

A third party Carousel:
[Nivo slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

Comment: But it have an additional feature, in which the centered images is zoomed... Also, i have an interview today and this might be included as a task, will internet be available in this kind of jquery based test?

Answer (score 0):

It's called a jQuery carousel. You can find some excellent examples here: http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55